# Why does the same hash function of Python and Rust produce different result for the same string?

Tags: python, rust, hash

TL;DR:

With the same parameters both hash functions produce the same results. There are few pre-conditions have to be met to achieve that.

I am building a system that has parts in Rust and Python. I need a hashing library that produces the same values for the same input on both ends. I thought that Python and Rust also uses SipHash 1-3 so I have tried to use that.

Python:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.c_size_t(hash(b'abcd')).value
14608482441665817778
>>> getsizeof(ctypes.c_size_t(hash(b'abcd')).value)
36
>>> type(b'abcd')
<class 'bytes'>
```

Rust:

```
use hashers::{builtin::DefaultHasher};
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

pub fn hash_str(s: &str) -> u64 {
    let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
    s.hash(&mut hasher);
    hasher.finish()
}

pub fn hash_bytes(b: &[u8]) -> u64 {
    let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
    b.hash(&mut hasher);
    hasher.finish()
}

fn test_hash_str() {
    let s1: &str = "abcd";
    let h1: u64 = hash_str(s1);

    assert_eq!(h1, 13543138095457285553);
}
#[test]
fn test_hash_bytes() {
    let b1: &[u8] = "abcd".as_bytes();
    let h1: u64 = hash_bytes(b1);

    assert_eq!(h1, 18334232741324577590);
}
```

Unfortunately I am not able to produce the same values on both end. Is there a way to get the same values somehow?

UPDATE:

After checkin Python's implementation there was a detail that I originally missed, so that Python uses a kind of random salt for every run. This means that the result I got from the Python function could not be the same as the Rust version.

This can be disabled with PYTHONHASHSEED=0 python ...

However this still does not make Python produce the same vales as the Rust version. I have tried custom SipHash implementations on both end. The results are consistent on both ends:

Both use siphasher::sip::SipHasher13; and DefaultHasher produces the same outputs. The result for a String is the same as for the &str but different for the .as_bytes() version.

```
   #[test]
    fn test_hash_string() {
        let s1: String = "abcd".to_string();
        let h1: u64 = hash_string(s1);

        assert_eq!(h1, 13543138095457285553);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_hash_str() {
        let s1: &str = "abcd";
        let h1: u64 = hash_str(s1);

        assert_eq!(h1, 13543138095457285553);
    }
    #[test]
    fn test_hash_bytes() {
        let b1: &[u8] = "abcd".as_bytes();
        let h1: u64 = hash_bytes(b1);

        assert_eq!(h1, 18334232741324577590);
    }
```

On Python side after disabling the randomization:

```
    sh = SipHash(c=1, d=3)
    h = sh.auth(0, "abcd")
    assert h == 16416137402921954953
```

Comment: The internal hash functions are meant for use by the language itself (Python, for example, uses it to implement the hash tables that underly the `dict` implementation.) If you need to *transfer* hash values from one program to another, look at (again, in Python) the algorithms implemented in the `hashlib` module.

Comment: A hash function is not a single thing, like (say) a stack data structure. There are infinitely many possible hash functions, some good for nothing, some good for some purpose, some for others. The important thing is to know *which* hash function you are using, so you can use the same one in another program or language; that's where standards like SHA256 are useful.

Comment: At the very least you'd need to disable the randomization. Did you?

Comment: @KellyBundy how do I disable the randomization? It seems Rust initializes the hash function with k0 = 0 and k1 = 0. What do you mean by randomization?

Comment: @chepner I know. Python and Rust both uses SipHash 1-3 as I stated. Maybe there are slight differences in the implementation and this is why those produce different results.

Comment: @chepner hashlib has a limited set of hash function that are primarily for security purposes and quite flow. SipHash is exactly right for the use case that I would like to use it for. In fact, it has better properties than the ones implemented in hashlib.

Comment: @Istvan See [-R](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-R) and [PYTHONHASHSEED](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED).

Comment: @KellyBundy woo I did not know about this! Thanks a lot. This explains why I am getting different results.

Comment: Does that mean you get the same results after disabling it? Then please post an answer with it. I can't test it myself. And I was already uncomfortable having *partially* answered it here.

Comment: @KellyBundy I am working on a test case to check. I am going to post it!! :)

Comment: @KellyBundy sadly no,  PYTHONHASHSEED=0 produces the same results but different from the Rust version.

Comment: @KellyBundy what is really interesting is that it produces the same value for "abcd" and b"abcd" while Rust produces different results.

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0456/#ascii-str-bytes-hash-collision

Comment: @KellyBundy This is interesting but I am still wondering how could I have the same values with a hash function from both languages. At least the results are consistent on both end.

Comment: What Python version are you using? And can you tell which one (if any) of Python or Rust computes the "correct" value?

Comment: Python 3.11. Not sure. Let me try to dig up more languages and results.

Comment: There is this site: https://md5hashing.net/

Comment: *"how could I have the same values with a hash function from both languages"* - chepner already answered that question. By using a library that is meant for that purpose. The internal hash function is specifically **not** meant for exchanging between languages and could change at any time. Rust even states that in its documentation of [`std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.DefaultHasher.html): `The internal algorithm is not specified, and so it and its hashes should not be relied upon over releases.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't use the internal hasher for external purposes. It is not meant to be predictable or compatible, it is simply meant to be used as an internal hashing.  Rust even [mentions it in its docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.DefaultHasher.html):

  > The internal algorithm is not specified, and so it and its hashes
  > should not be relied upon over releases.
- Don't use Rust's `.hash()` functionality of types. It's also not meant for external hashes; it does some unspecified internal binarization of the data. Use the hasher's `.write` functionality directly to feed it binary data.

That said, the solution is to use a specific hashing library for your purpose of compatibility, not the internal one.

In Rust, this is probably [`siphasher`](https://crates.io/crates/siphasher) if you want siphash-1-3. I'm unsure about Python, though, as I didn't use it in a while.

Here's an example code for Rust:

```rust
use siphasher::sip::SipHasher13;

use std::hash::Hasher;

pub fn hash_str(s: &str) -> u64 {
    hash_bytes(s.as_bytes())
}

pub fn hash_bytes(b: &[u8]) -> u64 {
    let mut hasher = SipHasher13::new();
    hasher.write(b);
    hasher.finish()
}

#[test]
fn test_hash_str() {
    let s1: &str = "abcd";
    let h1: u64 = hash_str(s1);

    assert_eq!(h1, 16416137402921954953);
}

#[test]
fn test_hash_bytes() {
    let b1: &[u8] = "abcd".as_bytes();
    let h1: u64 = hash_bytes(b1);

    assert_eq!(h1, 16416137402921954953);
}
```

---

Note that while I really don't recommend it, the same is true for Rust's internal hasher:

```rust
use std::hash::Hasher;

fn main() {
    let mut hasher = std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher::new();
    hasher.write("abcd".as_bytes());
    println!("{}", hasher.finish());
}
```

```
16416137402921954953
```

---

### Background

So why does `s.hash()` and `s.as_bytes().hash()` behave weirdly?

Let's write a simple debug hasher:

```rust
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

struct DebugHasher;

impl Hasher for DebugHasher {
    fn finish(&self) -> u64 {
        0
    }

    fn write(&mut self, bytes: &[u8]) {
        println!("   write: {:?}", bytes);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = "abcd";
    println!("--- s ---");
    s.hash(&mut DebugHasher);
    println!("--- s.as_bytes() ---");
    s.as_bytes().hash(&mut DebugHasher);
}
```

```
--- s ---
   write: [97, 98, 99, 100]
   write: [255]
--- s.as_bytes() ---
   write: [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
   write: [97, 98, 99, 100]
```

Now we have our answer:

- `s` seems to append `0xff`.
  This can also be seen in [its source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/hash/mod.rs.html#569):

  ```rust
  fn write_str(&mut self, s: &str) {
      self.write(s.as_bytes());
      self.write_u8(0xff);
  }
  ```
- `s.as_bytes()` seems to attach weird bytes at the front. In [its source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/hash/mod.rs.html#962), it can be seen that this is the length of the string:

  ```rust
  #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
  #[rustc_const_unstable(feature = "const_hash", issue = "104061")]
  impl<T: ~const Hash> const Hash for [T] {
      #[inline]
      fn hash<H: ~const Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
          state.write_length_prefix(self.len());
          Hash::hash_slice(self, state)
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you! This was really enlightening.

Comment: It may be interesting to mention _why_ such extraneous bytes are added. In short, it's about differentiating catenations. Imagine a tuple of 2 fields: `("Hello, World", "")` vs `("Hello, ", "World!")`. Those are not the same tuples, hence they should produce different hashes. The same goes with slices. In order to differentiate, the extraneous pieces of data (prefix or suffix) are added.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't get it. Why would something need to be added to those tuples?

Comment: @KellyBundy: Those tuples are not equal, hence it would be better if their hashes were different. If you just hash the sequence `'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'` for both, since you start from the same sequence, you get the same hash. For a better quality hash -- one that differentiates between the two tuples -- you need to introduce _some_ difference between the two. In Rust, the choice was to add a suffix marker for strings (using a byte which never occurs in UTF-8) and a prefix-length for slices (more expensive, but `T` being unknown, no marker would work).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ah, so the `'!'` in the second tuple is a typo? And tuples hash by concatenating their elements and hashing the result of that? I think Python does that differently, the tuple elements get hashed separately and their hashes are then combined  with a different hash algorithm.

Comment: @KellyBundy: I forgot it in the first tuple, actually, and can't edit now. But yes, the two tuples were supposed to contain strings which once catenated would be equal.